# fiddler modify response header

Tags: fiddler, fiddler-everywhere

I'm working with an API that doesn't yet have CORS setup. So, instead of waiting until that's setup, I thought I could use fiddler to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the responses coming from the server. I haven't used fiddler for a while and can't figure out how to add headers to the response. Is this not supported in the free version of fiddler-everywhere?

It's not ideal, but I found a workaround. After the requests have gone off once, I right-click the ones I'm interested in and select "Add new rule". The rule will automatically do an exact match to the URL and sets the action of "Return manually crafted response" If I edit the rule, the header can be added in the raw text.

Comment: If you have already used Fiddler and you are on Windows I recommend to you to stay with Fiddler. Fiddler is IMHO still way better... Just search for "Fiddler classic" to find the old .Net based version.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that was still available. Link if anyone else finds it useful https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: The workaround is actually the way to go! The Auto Responder is one of the most powerful functionality and its idea is to allow you to mock server responses. So using the manually crafted response AR ACTION is the right way to tackle this task.